# How to numpad lock

Tags: autohotkey

I have a keyboard without numpad and num lock, so I want to ask how to numlock 3 and 4 with autohotkey. For example at press Crt+L.

I can be satisfied with a script that press E continuesly.

Comment: Please explain more what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "how to numlock 3 and 4"? What kind of keyboard do you have?

Comment: Yes, sorry @user3419297 I have a 70% keyboard, the problem is in last epoch, a arpg, I usually locked some habilitys with numLock, to use constanly, I assign the hability to numpad0 or numpad2 and with numlock I do they are pressed constanly. Now I cant do that with this keyboard, and I think should be easy with AHK.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. You mention numlock 3 and 4, but then you say you want it to press E continuously. I see you posted a solution but it doesn't press E at all.... Please edit your question to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
Control & L::
Toggle := !Toggle
loop
{
    If not Toggle
        break
    Send {numpad2} {numpad3}
    Sleep 1000 * 60 * 4    
}
return
```

This works, but I think there is better options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).